# Parse JSON from unicode string as dictionaries

Tags: python, json, dictionary, unicode

I have a JSON input that consists of a list of dictionaries as unicode characters:
Example:

```
input = u'[{
        attributes: {
            NAME: "Name_1ĂĂÎÎ",
            TYPE: "Tip1",
            LOC_JUD: "Bucharest",
            LAT_LON: "234343/432545",
            S70: "2342345",
            MAP: "Map_one",
            SCH: "1:5000,
            SURSA: "PPP"
        }
    }, {
        attributes: {
            NAME: "NAME_2șțț",
            TYPE: "Tip2",
            LOC_JUD: "cea",
            LAT_LON: "123/54645",
            S70: "4324",
            MAP: "Map_two",
            SCH: "1:578000",
            SURSA: "PPP"
        }
    }
]
'
```

How can I parse this string into a list of dictionaries?  I tried to do this using:

```
import json
json_d = json.dumps(input)
print type(json_d)  # string object / Not list of dicts
json_obj = json.loads(json_d)  # unicode object / Not list of dicts
```

I cannot parse the contents of the JSON:

```
print json_obj[0]["attributes"]
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I am using Python 2.7.11. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Just do `json.loads(input)`. The dumps is the opposite process, you don't need it.

Comment: But he'll be needing the correctly stringified json. The current input doesn't have properties wrapped inside quotes. Which will be a problem, i guess.

Comment: You need to use `json.loads` not `json.dumps`. `load` is for *deserializing*. `dump` is for *serializing*. You were serializing a unicode string *into a JSON string*.

Comment: Agreed with @Nishant Srivastava . Please check input with JSON Validator. http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @NishantSrivastava Which means that the unicode string I recieve is not a JSON?

Comment: @DineshPundkar The input cannot be validated

Comment: BTW, you shouldn't use `input`as a variable name because that masks the built-in `input` function. OTOH, the Python 2 `input` function is potentially dangerous, so I guess masking it is an improvement. ;)

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks for the tip. I will be more careful with variable naming ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a simplified example:

```
s = '[{attributes: { a: "foo", b: "bar" } }]'
```

The main problem is your string is not in a valid JSON:

```
>>> json.loads(s)
[...]
JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 3 (char 2)
```

If the input is generated by you, then fix it. If it comes from somewhere else, then you will need to edit it before loading it with the `json` module.

Note how having a proper JSON, the `.load()` method works as expected:

```
>>> s = '[{"attributes": { "a": "foo", "b": "bar" } }]'
>>> json.loads(s)
[{'attributes': {'a': 'foo', 'b': 'bar'}}]
>>> type(json.loads(s))
list
```

Comment: I recieve the input from somewhere else. If I edit my JSON as: '''s = '[{"attributes": { "a": "foo", "b": "bar" } }]' ''', and then run 'json.loads(s)', I get a string, not a list of dictionaries...

Comment: @Litwos: see my updated answer, if the JSON is right, the method works (you can reproduce that yourself). ;-)

Comment: It works like that, thank you. I will now try to modify the input

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, your input data is not JSON. Ideally, that should be fixed upstream so that you *do* get valid JSON.

However, if that's out of your control you can convert that data to JSON.

The main problem is all those unquoted keys. We can fix that by using a regex to search for a valid name in the first field on each line. If a valid name is found we wrap it in double quotes.

```
import json
import re

source = u'''[{
        attributes: {
            NAME: "Name_1ĂĂÎÎ",
            TYPE: "Tip1",
            LOC_JUD: "Bucharest",
            LAT_LON: "234343/432545",
            S70: "2342345",
            MAP: "Map_one",
            SCH: "1:5000",
            SURSA: "PPP"
        }
    }, {
        attributes: {
            NAME: "NAME_2șțț",
            TYPE: "Tip2",
            LOC_JUD: "cea",
            LAT_LON: "123/54645",
            S70: "4324",
            MAP: "Map_two",
            SCH: "1:578000",
            SURSA: "PPP"
        }
    }
]
'''

# Split source into lines, then split lines into colon-separated fields
a = [s.strip().split(': ') for s in source.splitlines()]

# Wrap names in first field in double quotes
valid_name = re.compile('(^\w+$)')
for row in a:
    row[0] = valid_name.sub(r'"\1"', row[0])

# Recombine the data and load it
data = json.loads(' '.join([': '.join(row) for row in a]))

# Test 

print data[0]["attributes"]
print '- ' * 30
print json.dumps(data, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
```

**output**

```
{u'LOC_JUD': u'Bucharest', u'NAME': u'Name_1\u0102\u0102\xce\xce', u'MAP': u'Map_one', u'SURSA': u'PPP', u'S70': u'2342345', u'TYPE': u'Tip1', u'LAT_LON': u'234343/432545', u'SCH': u'1:5000'}
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
[
    {
        "attributes": {
            "LOC_JUD": "Bucharest", 
            "NAME": "Name_1ĂĂÎÎ", 
            "MAP": "Map_one", 
            "SURSA": "PPP", 
            "S70": "2342345", 
            "TYPE": "Tip1", 
            "LAT_LON": "234343/432545", 
            "SCH": "1:5000"
        }
    }, 
    {
        "attributes": {
            "LOC_JUD": "cea", 
            "NAME": "NAME_2șțț", 
            "MAP": "Map_two", 
            "SURSA": "PPP", 
            "S70": "4324", 
            "TYPE": "Tip2", 
            "LAT_LON": "123/54645", 
            "SCH": "1:578000"
        }
    }
]
```

Note that this code is a little fragile. It works with data that's in the format shown in the question, but it *won't* work if there are more than one key-value pair on a line.

As I said earlier, the best way to fix this problem is upstream, where the non-JSON is being produced.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Indeed, the format is not always like that, so I need to solve the problem upstream.